# Android Studio Could Not Resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am extremely new to android development and I just installed android Studio on my Windows machine and I created a project named MyFirstApp. It starts the gradle build but it fails with two errors. Here is an image of the errors. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.
I am using Kotlin To make this project.

RAM: 8GB
Processor: Intel i5 9400
GPU: Integrated Intel UHD 630
Android Studio Version: Android Studio Arctic Fox| 2020.3.1, Patch 3

**Error 1**

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3 > com.android.tools:common:30.0.3
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.0.3
      > No cached version of org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.4.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.3
      > No cached version of commons-io:commons-io:2.4 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of commons-io:commons-io:2.4 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.0.3
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.3
      > No cached version of org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.squareup:javapoet:1.10.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.squareup:javapoet:1.10.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.squareup:javapoet:1.10.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.0.3-7396180
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-gradle-proto:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.6.0
      > No cached version of com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.6.0
      > No cached version of com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.3
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:1.21.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.3
      > No cached version of io.grpc:grpc-core:1.21.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of io.grpc:grpc-core:1.21.1 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.21.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.3
      > No cached version of io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.21.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.21.1 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.21.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.3
      > No cached version of io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.21.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.21.1 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.21.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.3
      > No cached version of io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.21.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.21.1 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.12.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.12.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.12.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
      > No cached version of org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc2 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc2 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.6.0
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3 > com.android.tools:common:30.0.3
      > No cached version of com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.32.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.32 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.32 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.6.0
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of javax.inject:javax.inject:1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of javax.inject:javax.inject:1 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.0.3
      > No cached version of net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3
      > No cached version of xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.3
      > No cached version of org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.0.3
      > No cached version of org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.3
      > No cached version of com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.3
      > No cached version of com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools:annotations:30.0.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.3 > com.android.tools:common:30.0.3
      > No cached version of com.android.tools:annotations:30.0.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools:annotations:30.0.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.0.3
      > No cached version of org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.6.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.3
      > No cached version of net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.6.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.6.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.0.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.0.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.0.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.3
      > No cached version of org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.0.3
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.6.0
      > No cached version of com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.6.0
      > No cached version of com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.6.0
      > No cached version of com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.60.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.60 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.60 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
      > No cached version of org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.android:signflinger:7.0.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.android:signflinger:7.0.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android:signflinger:7.0.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.0.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.0.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.0.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:8.4.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:8.4.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:8.4.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.0.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.0.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.0.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.android:zipflinger:7.0.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.android:zipflinger:7.0.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android:zipflinger:7.0.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:apksig:7.0.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:apksig:7.0.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:apksig:7.0.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.0.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.0.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.0.3 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.3
      > No cached version of com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0 available for offline mode.

Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

**Error 2**

````
No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project ```
````

Comment: could you send a photo of your project level build.gradle?. Check if mavenCentral() is included in your list of directories

Comment: So did you try what it says and disable offline mode? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

Android studio is unable to resolve artifacts as `offline mode` for `gradle` is enabled. You can disable it from **Gradle Tool window** on the right side of your **Android studio**, using **Toggle offline mode** option in it, Refer to below image

[image]

If you do not have **Gradle Tool window** on the right side of your android studio, you can enable it from **View** > **Tool Windows** > **Gradle**

Comment: Sorry to say But that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Yes When I toggle Offline mode off it shows ```Enable Gradle offline mode and sync```  and shows ```Disable Gradle offline mode and sync ``` when I toggle it on

Comment: Disable Gradle offline mode and then sync. using `sync project with gradle`

Comment: If you are not getting `Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project` error. Open your project level Gradle and check if you have `mavenCentral()` in `repositories` block.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I disabled the offline mode and I solved the error but I get a different error now '''Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.31/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.31.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed'''. Now What's This !!

Comment: Add `google()` and `mavenCentral()` to `repositories` of your project level `build.gradle`

Comment: @AarushSoni this error is occurs when Android Studio is not able to download files from the internet. Make sure you have an active internet connection and then try again.

Comment: Yes thanks for the info I think that should fix the problem As far as I know the project level build file is app/build.gradle so since I am as new as a baby in android development can you just say me where should we add the google() and mavenCentral() block. Here is my Build.gradle (project level).